# why unable to change css X,Y parameters using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Am working with this example [`jsfiddele`](http://jsfiddle.net/mssjdb/yebjc/).
Here am trying to move two images one in X direction and another in Y direction.
Suppose if i want to change starting position of an image like in X axis, am trying to change css left, and for y position, am trying to change css top.

Here my doubts are like

If i want to change position towards X axis/Y axis why these are not working?

And here i want to change end postion of image also. But am not getting how to change this.
like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes toptobottom-move {
    100% {
        top: 73%;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
```

How i can change this using jquery?

Comment: You missed jQuery in fiddle settings, look at Frameworks and Extensions on sidebar and set jQuery

Comment: @ArtemFitiskin. Thanks. added here.  http://jsfiddle.net/mssjdb/yebjc/1/

Comment: If your actual question is about how to manipulate keyframes using JavaScript(?), then this might help: http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all, create a new div for yours inputs

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
   X:<input type="text" id="lefttoright" value="10"/>
   Y:<input type="text" id="toptobottom" value="10"/><br>
   End X:<input type="text" id="endlefttoright" value="10"/>
   End  Y:<input type="text" id="endtoptobottom" value="10"/>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".test input").change(function(){
        var val=this.value+"%"; 
        alert(val);
       $('.lefttoright').css("top", val);
       $('.toptobottom').css("left", val);
    });  
});
```

It works to me :D hope helps you